# how to index xml in solr with same tags but different values

Tags: solr

An xml has 2 sets of similar tags with different data.

```
<address>
    <door_num>100</door_num>
    <street>hundred street</street>
    <city>XYZ</city>
</address>
<address>
    <door_num>200</door_num>
    <street>two hundred street</street>
    <city>ABC</city>
    <active>1</active>
</address>
```

What is the best way to index this? Search by door_num 100 and city XYZ must return the document; whereas search by door_num 100 and city ABC must not return any document. Storing as multivalues does not help here. Also note that, the second set of address with door_num 200 may or may not be present in the xml. Please suggest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Model this data as [nested documents](http://yonik.com/solr-nested-objects/), the Address info would be stored in nested docs, and then you can query them so that both door_num and city need to match on the same nested doc.

Regarding how to actually get them into the index, you have several options:

1. write some java (or groovy or any other jvm lang) code with SolrJ, build your docs on the client side, and index them.
2. if you don't like java, you can still write any other lang code on the client side, and build your docs as xml/json that Solr can ingest, index them.
3. if you don't want to write any code at all, try with [DIH and XPathEntityProcessor](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler#XPathEntityProcessor), you might achieve all you need.

Comment: Thanks for the details. This is helpful.